# No more than one record creation and check record collision of similar type

Tags: apex, trigger, before-trigger, record

I've created a custom object for Leaves which allows the users under my org to apply for leaves. I've added three types of leaves such as Casual Leave, Sick Leave & Leave without Pay. I've used an Apex Trigger to check and limit the creation of only one record by one user per day but this Apex is creating a problem in org because it isn't allowing the users to apply for pre-planned leaves, i.e. if a user is applying for Sick Leave for the day he/she should also be allowed to apply for other leaves like Casual & Unpaid for different dates on the same day.

Fields I've used:

- `Start_Date__c (Date type)`
- `End_Date__c (Date type)`
- `Leave_Type__c (Picklist type)`

I want to use a trigger dependent on the `Start_Date__c` & `Leave_Type__c`

The Apex Currently in use:

```
trigger LeaveRecordDuplicateTrigger on New_Casual_Leave__c (before insert) {
    for(New_Casual_Leave__c a:Trigger.new)
    {
        string uid = userinfo.getName();
        List<New_Casual_Leave__c> acc=[select Id, CreatedDate, Contact__r.Account.Name,   Start_Date__c, Leave_Type__c from New_Casual_Leave__c 
                                        where (Contact__r.Account.Name = :uid 
                                        AND CreatedDate = TODAY) 
                                        and Leave_Type__c =a.Leave_Type__c];
           if(acc.size()>0)
           {
               a.adderror('One leave is already applied for the Day For ' + uid);
           }
       }  

}
```

//Getting error while using the above code: **Error: Compile Error: Unexpected token 'a.Leave_Type__c'. at line 5 column 229**

What changes to be made to avoid errors? Where am I going wrong?

Comment: You have omitted the colon character for the bind variable in the SOQL statement, which was shown in the answer to your duplicate question.

Comment: You are checking account name `Contact__r.Account.Name = :uid` with current user's name,using `string uid = userinfo.getName();`. That's incorrect in every sense.

Answer (score 0):

You are checking

> if the user has already applied for a leave for **CreatedDate**, in which case you will always get a `False` if the user has applied for another type of leave the same day.

What you should be doing is

- Creating a map of leaves (date type) from the system(have those records queried beforehand), and then checking in a trigger loop (trigger.new) to see if the user already has a leave record in that range and then allow or disallow the leave submission.

On sidenote, you should not use [`SOQL`](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Apex_Code_Best_Practices) inside loops, as suggested above use [maps](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_map.htm) and loop over them.

Answer (score 0):

Problem with your SOQL in the trigger.
Remove the brackets(())

```
List<New_Casual_Leave__c> acc=[select Id, CreatedDate, Contact__r.Account.Name,   Start_Date__c, Leave_Type__c from New_Casual_Leave__c 
                                where Contact__r.Account.Name = :uid 
                                AND CreatedDate = TODAY 
                                and Leave_Type__c =a.Leave_Type__c];
```

Comment: Still seeing the same error even after removing the brackets.

Comment: Ensure you have the field (Leave_Type__c]) added to the FLS